# Create flattened array from array of JSON values Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, trino

Say I have the following array of json variables in my data:

```
pets
---
[{"type":"dog", "name":"fido"}, {"type":"cat", "name":"steve"}, {"type":"dog", "name":"carl"}]
[{"type":"dog", "name":"ellie"}, {"type":"fish", "name":"goldie"}]
[{"type":"cat", "name":"simone"}, {"type":"lizard", "name":"sparky"}]
```

How would I structure an SQL query such that I can have an array of *dog names* for each of the rows that looks like this:

```
dog_names
---
["fido", "carl"]
["ellie"]
[]
```

Currently, the farthest I have gotten is filtering the data using:

```
filter(pets, r -> r.type= 'dog')
```

This filters the array properly, and in instances where the cardinality of the array is 1, allows me to correctly query using the index, but I would like to capture all names (and not break when no dogs are found).

To clarify, the data type of pets is ROW.

Comment: Can you please specify the result of `select typeof(Pets)`

Comment: it is of type ROW, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the usage it seems that you have array of `ROW`'s, so you can use [`transform`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#transform) on the filtered array in the similar way:

```
transform(filter(pets, r -> r.type= 'dog'), r -> r.name)
```